# old software compatibility with el capitan

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan

I have the next problem. I have a .pkg installation package which is quite all, at least older than El Capitan OS. The problem is (after looking on the internet) this .pkg writes some binaries to /usr/bin and that is something not permited in El Capitan OS anymore, it should be written to /usr/local/bin.

I have found two solutions on the internet (well actually three) which are:

-disabling SIP, which is not recomended.

-waiting for someone to redoo the .pkg (i do not want to wait)

-i was thinking in some simbolik link between /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin so when it tries to write to /usr/bin it really writes to /usr/local/bin

-Redoo the .pkg (no idea at all).

Thank for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a tool like [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com) to extract the files out of the pkg and copy them into `/usr/local/bin` yourself. Pacifist will also let you extract any preflight/postflight scripts that the pkg runs so you can run the equivalent setup commands yourself.